# Setting a background image/view to live camera view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to set a background for a particular view controller to show a live camera view? If so, could one lead me in the right direction to make this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, definitely possible. You can embed live camera feed in UIView, which you can place anywhere you like.

Start by reading here: [AVFoundation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) - this is your framework

Particular class that you are looking for is [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009524)

Which works in unison with [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009521)

And this is an example project that covers everything you need: [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 8):

Import:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

To add camera view to a controller's view add this code in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
[session addInput:input];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];

[session startRunning];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to grab and understand this [apple sample code, called AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112).  You'll see in the code how to create an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.  You'll insert this as a sublayer of a UIView that you'll use as your "background".

Once you've got that working, that UIView will be just like any other part of your view hierarchy.  You can treat it like a background UIImageView (albeit, one that consumes a lot more batter power).