# How to do the animation like iButterfly?

Tags: ios, animation

I need to do a same catching action like [iButterfly](http://ibutterfly.hk/eng/howtouse.html#tag12).But I am a fresh with iOS Animation,so can you give me some ideas?

Comment: If you are a fresher with iOS Animation, there are too many thing you have to learn first.

Comment: Yes,sure!I would like to learn iOS Animation according to do a app like iButterfly.

Answer (score 0):

Take at look at this [sprite kit primer](https://www.udemy.com/spritekit/) or if you want to use the third party library cocos2d [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/simple-animation-with-changing-images-with-cocos2d/) is a simple animation tutorial. You could also do your own animation system. I would recommend using either sprite kit or cocos2d as a lot of the work is done for you and they are heavily optimised. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ben Avery.I would like to learn iOS Animation according to do a app like iButterfly,I have do it with 3 layers, first is camera, and then it is butter that flying, the last layer is catching.Is it right way?

Comment: I would do it by having 1 camera layer set as the background (take a look at this for accessing the camera. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793734/setting-a-background-image-view-to-live-camera-view Then I would have 2 sprite kit layers layer one mid ground : would be the "butterfly" and layer two foreground would be the catch rect.