# Live Camera Background iOS Objective-C Using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to use `UIImagePickerController` class for my live camera background?

My App uses `UIImagepickercontroller` for capturing images and video. My design is like this:

Two buttons (button 1 for Photo, button 2 for Video) in Home View Controller, but at the same time, my background is a like camera. I have successfully implemented the photo and video function. All are complete except for the live background.

I already tried this: [Setting a background image/view to live camera view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793734/setting-a-background-image-view-to-live-camera-view)
using AVFoundation. But it makes the camera load so slow. And sometimes the background freezes.

My code for video and photo:

1. VIDEO:

   ```
   -(IBAction)videoActionButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"video button has been clicked");

   // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    //    VideoViewController *videoViewController = [[VideoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
   //    [self.navigationController pushViewController:videoViewController animated:YES];


   if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
   {
   videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   videoRecorder.delegate = self;

   NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
   NSArray *videoMediaTypesOnly = [mediaTypes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF contains %@)", @"movie"]];

   if ([videoMediaTypesOnly count] == 0)       //Is movie output possible?
   {
       UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry but your device does not support video recording"
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [actionSheet showInView:[[self view] window]];
       // [actionSheet autorelease];
   }
   else
   {
       //Select front facing camera if possible
       if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront])
           videoRecorder.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

       videoRecorder.mediaTypes = videoMediaTypesOnly;
       videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
       videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 600;           //Specify in seconds (600 is default)

       [self presentViewController:videoRecorder animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
   // [videoRecorder release];
   }
   else
   {
   //No camera is availble
   }

   // [imagePickerController release];

   //    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   //    UINavigationController *videoViewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoViewController"];
    //    [self presentViewController:videoViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];

   }
   ```
2. PHOTO:

   ```
      -(IBAction)photoActionButton:(id)sender {
       NSLog(@"photo button has been clicked");

       photoButtonClicked = true;

       UIImagePickerControllerSourceType type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

       if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:type]){

           UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
           picker.allowsEditing = NO;


           picker.delegate   = self;

           picker.sourceType = type;


           [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
       }

   }
   ```

PS: Can someone help me with code format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) property of of UIImagePickerController.

1. Create a UIImagePickerController
2. Configure the view with buttons(view should be clear background color)
3. Set the view as cameraOverlayView of the image picker
4. Present imagepicker

Answer (score 0):

You should use AVCam for this.

https://github.com/gabro/AVCam

Thanks