# iOS and SpriteKit camera background

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am developing a game for iOS using Scenekit and maybe GamePlayKit. What I want is for the background of the main game play to be set to a live camera feed. That should be simple enough. A little googling brought me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793734/setting-a-background-image-view-to-live-camera-view)`question. My question however, is will a technique like the one in the linked question work well with SpriteKit? The question deals with setting the background with UIKit. Can I use this option with SceneKit too or do I have to use some sort of SceneKit specific way to set the background like so?

Comment: if you plan on the camera images being the far background with nothing behind it,  then UIKit will work fine,  you just need to make sure that this view goes behind the SceneKit's view, and make sure that the SceneKits view has a clear background color